# JQuery Post don't work json data type

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have this code in javascript:

```
$.post('AccessDB.php', {add:add, seriesid:seriesid, lang:lang}, function(data) {
            alert(data);

            if (data.returned == "Verified"){

                notification('Success notification');
            } else if (data.returned == "NotVerified") {

            notification('Oh noes! Something went wrong', true);

            }
        }, "json");
```

that I call when I press a button, and then in the `AccessDB.php` I do this to return the value:

```
echo json_encode(array('returned' => 'Error'));
```

but the alert that return from javascript is this:

```
[object Object]
```

and is not the value Error, instead if I delete the `"json"` from javascript the value in the alert is:

```
{"returned":"Error"}
```

but I can't handle this value because I delete the json datatype, anyone can tell me how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is an object. Try:

```
alert(data.returned);
```

Answer (score 1):

What an `alert()` does is takes that variable you pass in and turns it into a string.

When you do `myObject.toString()` it returns `[object Object]`, that is the expected behavior. You are not going to see what is in an object with alert.

Use `console.dir(data)` or `console.log(data)` to get that information.

Comment: Withdrew my previous comment in light of the edits you made.  Though it's also important to note that not every browser has a console to log to.  Chrome has one natively, firefox can have one added with firebug (and might natively support a console too now) but IE doesn't as far as I'm aware, though I can't get newer than 9 on my XP VM

Comment: To add, IE's console is opened by pressing `F12`

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response has been converted into a JavaScript object. When you alert a normal JavaScript object, it will appear as [object Object]. You should still be able to access the properties of the object. Try `alert(data.returned)` for example.